# Is it possible to read FTP files without writing them using Python?

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to read files using Python's ftplib without writing them. Something roughly equivalent to:

```
def get_page(url):
    try:
        return urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    except:
        return ""
```

but using FTP.

I tried:

```
def get_page(path):
    try:
        ftp = FTP('ftp.site.com', 'anonymous', 'passwd')
        return ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+path, open('page').read())
    except:
        return ''
```

but this doesn't work. The only examples in the docs involve writing files using the `ftp.retrbinary('RETR README', open('README', 'wb').write)` format. Is it possible to read ftp files without writing first?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Well, you have the answer right in front of you: The `FTP.retrbinary` method accepts as second parameter a reference to a function that is called whenever file content is retrieved from the FTP connection.

Here is a simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from ftplib import FTP

def writeFunc(s):
  print "Read: " + s

ftp = FTP('ftp.kernel.org') 
ftp.login()
ftp.retrbinary('RETR /pub/README_ABOUT_BZ2_FILES', writeFunc)
```

You should implement `writeFunc` so that it actually appends the data read to an internal variable, something like this, which uses a callable object:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from ftplib import FTP

class Reader:
  def __init__(self):
    self.data = ""
  def __call__(self,s):
     self.data += s

ftp = FTP('ftp.kernel.org') 
ftp.login()
r = Reader()
ftp.retrbinary('RETR /pub/README_ABOUT_BZ2_FILES', r)

print r.data
```

**Update:** I realized that there is a module in the Python standard library that is meant for this kind of things, [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from ftplib import FTP
from io import BytesIO

ftp = FTP('ftp.kernel.org') 
ftp.login()
r = BytesIO()
ftp.retrbinary('RETR /pub/README_ABOUT_BZ2_FILES', r.write)

print r.getvalue()
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't realize the callback could be a user defined function

Comment: For Python 3, retrbinary requires BytesIO, because it returns bytes, not string. If you want StringIO, try ftp.retrlines()

Comment: @TimRichardson I tried `ftp.retelines(f'RETR {filename}')` returns BrokenPipeError, trackback shows there're some problem in file encoding (at `self.sock.sendall(line.encode(self.encoding))` in putline). The file I'm trying to get is md5 hash (link: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/baseline/pubmed23n0003.xml.gz.md5)

Comment: @jimmymcheung you have a typo, it is not "retelines"

Comment: @TimRichardson thanks, but it was the typo here. I checked the script and it was correct (tho now I just use `retrbinary` and comment out the `retrlines` script, because I read the documentation more carefully and found `retrlines` is not read file in "string" mode)

Answer (score 0):

With retrlines, if the file retrieved is in text mode, things can be even more simple and you get directly a list, like readlines :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from ftplib import FTP
    
ftp = FTP('ftp.kernel.org') 
ftp.login()
r = []
ftp.retrlines('RETR /pub/README_ABOUT_BZ2_FILES', r.append)

print(r)
```

for the reverse process (send from BytesIO) see [How can I send a StringIO via FTP in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449269/how-can-i-send-a-stringio-via-ftp-in-python-3)