# How can I send a StringIO via FTP in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, stringio, bytesio

I want to upload a text string as a file via FTP.

```
import ftplib
from io import StringIO

file = StringIO()
file.write("aaa")
file.seek(0)


with ftplib.FTP() as ftp:
    ftp.connect("192.168.1.104", 2121)
    ftp.login("ftp", "ftp123")
    ftp.storbinary("STOR 123.txt", file)
```

This code returns an error:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace, so we can know which line is causing the error?

Comment: Try changing _line 5_ to `fileHandler.write(u"aaa")` and _line 13_ to `ftp.storbinary(u"STOR 123.txt",fileHandler,bufsize)`

Answer (score 6):

This can be a point of confusion in python 3, especially since tools like `csv` will only write `str`, while `ftplib` will only accept `bytes`.

You can deal with this is by using `io.TextIOWrapper`:

```
import io
import ftplib


file = io.BytesIO()

file_wrapper = io.TextIOWrapper(file, encoding='utf-8')
file_wrapper.write("aaa")

file.seek(0)

with ftplib.FTP() as ftp:
    ftp.connect(host="192.168.1.104", port=2121)
    ftp.login(user="ftp", passwd="ftp123")

    ftp.storbinary("STOR 123.txt", file)
```

Comment: this also seems to work if I only do `file_wrapper.seek(0)` instead of `file.seek(0)`, my file was stored in ftp as I expected it, so can either of the `io` stream be seeked? @stephen-fuhry

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as well

```
binary_file = io.BytesIO()
text_file = io.TextIOWrapper(binary_file)

text_file.write('foo')
text_file.writelines(['bar', 'baz'])

binary_file.seek(0)
ftp.storbinary('STOR foo.txt', binary_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me in python 3.

```
content_json = bytes(json.dumps(content),"utf-8")
with io.StringIO(content_json) as fp:
    ftps.storlines("STOR {}".format(filepath), fp)
```

Comment: `with io.BytesIO(content_json)` and not StringIO : you cannot store bytes in StringIO. 
With this correction done, your suggestion works fine

Comment: for the reverse process (get StringIO via FTP) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208957/is-it-possible-to-read-ftp-files-without-writing-them-using-python/74949100#74949100