# How do I count the number of line in a FTP file without downloading it locally while using Python

Tags: python, ftp

So I need to be able to read and count the number of lines from a FTP server WITHOUT downloading it to my local machine while using Python.

I know the code to connect to the server:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('example.com')  //Object ftp set as server address
ftp.login ('username' , 'password')  // Login info
ftp.retrlines('LIST')  // List file directories
ftp.cwd ('/parent folder/another folder/file/')  //Change file directory
```

I also know the basic code to count the number of line **If it is already downloaded/stored locally :**

```
with open('file') as f:  
...     count = sum(1 for line in f)  
...     print (count)
```

I just need to know how to connect these 2 pieces of code without having to download the file to my local system.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: You need to *download* the *data* anyway to count the lines; you can only avoid saving it on disk.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know FTP doesn't provide any kind of functionality to read the file content without actually downloading it. However you could try using something like [Is it possible to read FTP files without writing them using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208957/is-it-possible-to-read-ftp-files-without-writing-them-using-python)
(You haven't specified what python you are using)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from ftplib import FTP

def countLines(s):
   print len(s.split('\n'))

ftp = FTP('ftp.kernel.org') 
ftp.login()
ftp.retrbinary('RETR /pub/README_ABOUT_BZ2_FILES', countLines)
```

Please take this code as a reference only

Answer (score 0):

There is a way: I adapted a piece of code that I created for processes csv files "on the fly".  Is implement by producer-consumer problem approach. Apply this pattern allows us to assign each task to a thread (or process) and show partial results for huge remote files. You can adapt it for ftp requests.

**Download stream is saved in queue and is consumed "on the fly"**. No HDD extra space is needed and memory efficient. Tested in Python 3.5.2 (vanilla) on Fedora Core 25 x86_64.

This is the source adapted for ftp (over http) retrieve:

```
from threading import Thread, Event
from queue import Queue, Empty
import urllib.request,sys,csv,io,os,time;
import argparse

FILE_URL = 'http://cdiac.ornl.gov/ftp/ndp030/CSV-FILES/nation.1751_2010.csv'


def download_task(url,chunk_queue,event):

    CHUNK = 1*1024
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    event.clear()

    print('%% - Starting Download  - %%')
    print('%% - ------------------ - %%')
    '''VT100 control codes.'''
    CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A'
    ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K'
    while True:
        chunk = response.read(CHUNK)
        if not chunk:
            print('%% - Download completed - %%')
            event.set()
            break
        chunk_queue.put(chunk)

def count_task(chunk_queue, event):
    part = False
    time.sleep(5) #give some time to producer
    M=0
    contador = 0
    '''VT100 control codes.'''
    CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A'
    ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K'
    while True:
        try:
            #Default behavior of queue allows getting elements from it and block if queue is Empty.
            #In this case I set argument block=False. When queue.get() and queue Empty ocurrs not block and throws a 
            #queue.Empty exception that I use for show partial result of process.
            chunk = chunk_queue.get(block=False)
            for line in chunk.splitlines(True):
                if line.endswith(b'\n'):
                    if part: ##for treat last line of chunk (normally is a part of line)
                        line = linepart + line
                        part = False
                    M += 1
                else: 
                ##if line not contains '\n' is last line of chunk. 
                ##a part of line which is completed in next interation over next chunk
                    part = True
                    linepart = line
        except Empty:
            # QUEUE EMPTY 
            print(CURSOR_UP_ONE + ERASE_LINE + CURSOR_UP_ONE)
            print(CURSOR_UP_ONE + ERASE_LINE + CURSOR_UP_ONE)
            print('Downloading records ...')
            if M>0:
                print('Partial result:  Lines: %d ' % M) #M-1 because M contains header
            if (event.is_set()): #'THE END: no elements in queue and download finished (even is set)'
                print(CURSOR_UP_ONE + ERASE_LINE+ CURSOR_UP_ONE)
                print(CURSOR_UP_ONE + ERASE_LINE+ CURSOR_UP_ONE)
                print(CURSOR_UP_ONE + ERASE_LINE+ CURSOR_UP_ONE)
                print('The consumer has waited %s times' % str(contador))
                print('RECORDS = ', M)
                break
            contador += 1
            time.sleep(1) #(give some time for loading more records) 

def main():


    chunk_queue = Queue()
    event = Event()
    args = parse_args()
    url = args.url

    p1 = Thread(target=download_task, args=(url,chunk_queue,event,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Thread(target=count_task, args=(chunk_queue,event,))
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

# The user of this module can customized one parameter:
#   + URL where the remote file can be found.

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--url', default=FILE_URL,
                        help='remote-csv-file URL')
    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Usage

```
$ python ftp-data.py -u <ftp-file>
```

Example:

```
python ftp-data-ol.py -u 'http://cdiac.ornl.gov/ftp/ndp030/CSV-FILES/nation.1751_2010.csv' 
The consumer has waited 0 times
RECORDS =  16327
```

Csv version on Github: https://github.com/AALVAREZG/csv-data-onthefly

Comment: Note: if run this script in Windows, VT100 Console Control Codes, only operate on VT100-compatible terminals.

Comment: This is way above my knowledge of Python(Im still learning), Im gonna need some time to figure out how I can use this. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: With some basic knowledge of multithreading and queue data structure, the code is very simple (I'm in the first stages of Python learning too) ;-).